# Can i capture at 20 fps with C++ and Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

i have a Raspberry Pi and installed on it the OpenCV and Guvcview. When i open Guvcview, i get ~ 17-21 fps but when i run a simple program (only capture from webcam and display frame) in C++ with Opencv, i get only 6 fps.

What is wrong? i need to configure Opencv to use Guvcview's configuration? why guvcview get 20 fps? What can i do?

thanks.

P.D. I've done the same in my computer and i get 29 fps in both cases.

//*********************************************************this is the code C++ :

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    time_t start, end; //variabile di tipo time_t , contiene tempo in sec. 
    // inizializzo contatore nella dichiarazione 
    int counter=0;

    int main()
    { time(&start);
    VideoCapture cap(1);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480); 

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    { cout << "could not capture";
    return 0; }

    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("camera", 1);
    char key = 'a';

    while(key != 27)
    {   cap.read( frame);
    imshow("camera", frame);

    //##################
    //time at the end of 1 show, Stop the clock and show FPS
    time(&end);
    ++counter;
    cout <<"fps: "<< counter/ difftime(end,start) <<endl <<endl;
    //##################

    key = waitKey(3); }

    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you try to use default resolution ?

Comment: do you mean remove: cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640); cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480); ?  ...but i need this resolution...can i set in another way?

Comment: yes, can you comment out those lines?

Comment: do you mean remove: cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640); cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480); ? ...but i need this resolution...can i set in another way?. Anyway i've tried it and i get 160x120 resolution.

Comment: is it faster in lower resolution?

Comment: Yes, can i keep this speed?

Comment: if your camera default resolution is low and you increase the resolution to 640x480, program may apply some expensive resizing operation and you may not maintain such a speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to do direct video capture via V4L, since OpenCV may do YUYV to RGB transformations and other stuff that involves floating point calculations, that are expensive on this kind of hardware. We have done many robotics projects on embedded systems and the rule of the thumb is that you will be always better of either directly using V4L or small 3rd party libraries like CMVision (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jbruce/cmvision/) to do image processing on embedded systems.

Comment: hi,
since i read your answer, i've studied about the possibility to use v4l API and the CMVision library. 
I only need to send these frames to a pc for the processing; do you think that sending YUV gray format may improve speed?

Comment: sorry, but how can i use/install Cmvision? i typed "make" from terminal but i get errors. thanks

Comment: Well, in our project we just included the Cmvision source files that we needed (since we also used a subpart - only capture and region searching), i guess you should also find the code that you need and just include those .c/.h files in your project. Well if you need to send them then maybe use a lossy compressed format like YUV 4:2:0 or if the images ar near FullHD MJPEG/H.264.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV is a heavy weight API and following tips may introduce minor improvements:

you can disable RGB conversion:

```
 cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB , false);
```

you can increase frame rate if its default frame rate is low:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 60);
```

Comment: It helped me increase FPS up to 65 at least!